# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Tags: php

Tengo este error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\conteo-votos-master\estadisticas.php
>   on line 62

Y este es mi codigo:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(empty($_SESSION['dni']) && !$login){
        header('Location: login.php');
        exit;
    }

    require "config.php";


?>
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <title>Conteo de Votos</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dhbhdrzi4tiry.cloudfront.net/cdn/sites/foundation.min.css">
        <style>
            td.logo {
                 /*padding: 0 0 3px 0;*/
                 width: 80px;
            }

           .logo img{
               margin: 0  0 0 0 ;
            }

          .input-group {
               margin-bottom: 0 !important;
            }
       </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="top-bar">
        <div class="top-bar-left">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="index.php">Registrar Votos</a></li>
                <li class="menu-text">Estadisticas</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row medium-8 large-7 ">
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr bgcolor="gray">
                <td></td>
                <td align="center">Total</td>
                <td align="center">1</td>
                <td align="center">2</td>
                <td align="center">3</td>
                <td align="center">4</td>
            </tr>

            <?php

            $sql = "call get_votos()";

            $res = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                echo "
                <tr>
                    <td><img src=\"logos/{$row['id']}.png\" width=40 height=40 border=0 alt='{$row['id']}'></td>
                    <td align='center'>{$row['c0']}</td>
                    <td align='center'>{$row['c1']}</td>
                    <td align='center'>{$row['c2']}</td>
                    <td align='center'>{$row['c3']}</td>
                    <td align='center'>{$row['c4']}</td>
                </tr>
                ";
            }

            ?>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://dhbhdrzi4tiry.cloudfront.net/cdn/sites/foundation.js"></script>
    <script>

        function enviarDatos(b){
            b.preventDefault();
            if (confirm("Desea guardar?")) {
                $("#datos").submit();
            }
        }

        $(document).foundation();

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Esta es la consulta SQL

```
<?php 
    require "config.php"; $mesa = $_GET['mesa']; 
    $sql = "select count(*) as total from votos where mesa = '$mesa'"; 
    $res = mysqli_query($link,$sql); 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res); 

    echo json_encode($row); 
    if ($row['total'] > 0 )
    { 
        echo "fail"; 
    }else{ 
        echo "ok"; 
    } 
?>
```

Agradecere vuestro apoyo.

Comment: cuando marca eso quiere decir que hubo un algún problema con tu consulta, y por ende regresa false (el booleano) y no el mysqli_result object, revisa tu consulta

Comment: <?php
require "config.php";
$mesa = $_GET['mesa'];
$sql = "select count(*) as total from votos where mesa = '$mesa'";
$res = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
echo json_encode($row);

if ($row['total'] > 0 ){
 echo "fail";
}else{
 echo "ok";
}
?>

Comment: Es mi consulta, al probarlo en el phpadmin, funciona normal.

Comment: Y hay una conexion viva y abierta?

Comment: Si asi es: <?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","votos");
?>